# Посоветуйте, как правильно подключать библиотеки к express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, best-practice

Встретился с проблемой архитектуры express приложения. Подскажите, как правильно реализовать подключение библиотек к проекту, Module Require или DI? Очень интересуют лучшие практики, желательно с примерами.

Например подключение к базе данных сейчас делаю таким образом, но есть некоторые сомнения

```js
//db.js
var mysql = require('promise-mysql');
var config = require('../config');

var db = mysql.createConnection(config.db);

module.exports = db;

//users.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  let db;
  try {
    db = await require('lib/db'); // <--

    await db.beginTransaction();
    const result = await db.query("SELECT 1 + 1 AS test");
    await db.commit();

    res.send(result);

  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  } finally {
    if (db && db.end) {
      db.end();
    }
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Структура

```
routes/users.js
lib/db.js
app.js
config.js
```

Comment: А, в чём выражаются сомнения?

Comment: То что require в теле обработчика, просто не наблюдал такого у других, в основном все делают через замыкания, возможно не просто так, а может дело привычки

Comment: тут проблема не в том, что require внутри обработчика, а в том, что при каждом запросе открывается новое подключение к БД. По сути, нужно строить логику так, чтобы во время работы сервера, подключение к БД было открыто всегда

Comment: Да это демо пример, но нужно использование транзакций, а то будет гонка данных, поэтому так и будет на запрос - соединение желательно из пула соединений, чтобы не терять время на открытие

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на Ваш вопрос сильно зависит от того в чём состоят Ваши сомнения и что Вы хотите получить в итоге.

Если проект небольшой и, что ещё лучше, одноразовый, можно и через require. Если же проект сложный, вполне вероятно придётся использовать DI и пр., чтобы  обеспечить нужную гибкость. Но и здесь опять же нужно понимать, чего вы хотите добиться при помощи того же DI. Просто чтобы не получилось неоправданного усложнения проекта по принципу "из пушки по воробьям".

Однако в любом случае в обработчик следует выносить только отправку данных клиенту или их получение от него. Их получение из БД, запись в БД, всевозможная обработка должны происходить в отдельных классах (загуглите про тот же MVC). Если не будет соответствующего разделения обязанностей между компонентами системы, все остальные архитектурные приёмы (DI, замыкания и пр.) пользы не принесут.

Comment: Да, довольно крупный - биллинг система. На этапе разработки 2 года назад уже закладывал уход от PHP, сейчас система разделена на backend как rest api сервис и frontend. Конечно используется принцип MVC и полной модульности системы, обязательно будет использован ORM, DI или его аналог, ACL. Поэтому так сильно интересует правильная архитектура, так как это долгосрочный проект с поддержкой

Comment: Тогда паттерны (не только MVC), SOLID и пр. должны стать Вашими добрыми "друзьями".

Comment: Только всё это выходит за рамки вопроса на SO, т.к. по таким вещам пишутся целые книги.

Comment: MVC, SOLID уже использую в PHP, просто не знаю как их правильно готовить в express

Comment: Всё это общие фундаментальные вещи, которые не зависят от платформы. Платформа определяет лишь особенности реализации. Попробуйте использовать те же принципы, но на JS.